# how to retrieve process status whose procees id is given from c program?

Tags: c, linux

I have to retrieve process status(whether process is running or stopped) whose procees  id is given from my  c program(i am using linux). i planned to use exec command
and written below statement

execv("ps -el|grep |awk '{print $2}'",NULL);

But it is not giving me desired output.

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: How are you passing the process ID that you're interested in to that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third field in `/proc/<pid>/stat` contains the process status: `R` if it's Running, `S` if it's Sleeping (there's a few others too, like `D` for Disk Wait and `Z` for Zombie).

Comment: how to use pipe and grep in execl command according to above reply below statement
execl("/bin/cat","bin/cat","/proc/1/stat") is giving whole line but i want to retrieve 3rd column only

Comment: Don't exec `cat` to read a file in C - use the builtin file reading functions `fopen()`, `fgets()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The exec call returns the error code corresponding to whether the execution of the program was successful or not.

If you fork a child process and then exec the command in the child process, you can read the its exit status in the parent process using the waitpid call.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt exec is the family of calls you require here. system(3) might be more ideal.